Delay in reloading HTML page after sending data from Google Sheet
i integrate google sheet in my html page, when i send my data, everyhing good -> data apear in google table, but i had big delay in few second, after my page reloaded and clean old data, that was written in page before.
Code form
 <form action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyge9dyR6OtyfE2lir6f4cI32kX-7QSSRAqEgIILZeR4Z2M3JSQqoPdDheuImIkwpRg/exec" method ="post" id="add-form" name="contact-form">
                            <input type="text" name="Name"  class="form-control" placeholder="Ім'я" required="required">
                            <input type="email" name="Email"  class="form-control" placeholder="Почта" required="required">
                            <input type="text" name="Mobile"  class="form-control" placeholder="Мобільний" required="required">
                         
                            <textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="Message" placeholder="Побажання"
                                    required="required"></textarea>
                            <button type="submit" class="site-btn">Відправити</button>
                        </form>

My script app script, in Google sheet extentions
const sheetName = 'dataSite'
const scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()

function intialSetup () {
  const activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  scriptProp.setProperty('key', activeSpreadsheet.getId())
}

function doPost (e) {
  const lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
  lock.tryLock(10000)

  try {
    const doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'))
    const sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName)

    const headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
    const nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1

    const newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
      return header === 'Date' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
    })

    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])

    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'success', 'row': nextRow }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  catch (e) {
    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }
}

My script in html page
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#add-form, #add-form2").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default form submission behavior
        alert('Повідомлення Відправлено !');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $(this).attr("action"),
            data: $(this).serialize(),

            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                // Handle the error (if needed)
                console.error(xhr.responseText);
            },
            success: function(response) {
                // After successful form submission, reset the form
                $("#add-form, #add-from2")[0].reset();
                window.close();
            }
        }).then(function() {
            // Reload the page after successful AJAX request
            window.location.reload();
        });
    });
});

If sombody know, why my data, does not disappear instantly after sending, but continues to be visible on the page for several seconds, tnx

Because you are not clearing it "instantly after sending", but when the response to the request you are making there, has arrived?

What need write in JS, that reload page instantly ?

You can clear the fields earlier, by calling the reset method of the forms before your AJAX request. (You will need to serialize the data before you do that then.) But the reload will still only happen, after the response to the AJAX request has arrived.
